# Get Duplicates in Range of Numbers

Tags: vb.net, linq, filtering

I have a DataTable that consists of roughly 2500 rows where the data looks like this:

```
+------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|    Date    | Number1 | Number2 | Number3 | Number4 |
+------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| 12/30/2017 |    1    |    11   |   19    |    72   |
| 12/29/2017 |    4    |    7    |   21    |    48   |
|    etc.    |   etc.  |   etc.  |   etc.  |   etc.  |
+------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

What I am wanting to do is get which range of numbers appear more than once. A couple of things to note, the minimum number is 1 and the maximum number is 100 and the numbers are sorted ascending based on its range which means that like in row1 of my sample data it is 1, 11, *19*, 72 and row2 it is 4, 7, *21*, 48.

I'm sure that this is probably trivial to do by simply doing multiple passes via a For/Next loop, but I'm really wanting something more concise like through a LINQ query or even through the [DataTable.Select](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

To clarify, I'm using Visual Basic .NET and the data is coming from a CSV file. Though if you provide a C# example, I can easily translate it.

Comment: What have you already tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: @Craig - I've tried converting the datatable's rows property to a DataRow to then select the desired columns. This returns a collection of Integer values, but this is where I get tripped up. I don't understand how to get the collections that appear more than once. I didn't know that it was relevant to the question.

Comment: Could you modify your example to include a duplicate that you are looking for?  Will it be another complete set of 1, 11, 19, 72?

Comment: Depending on how you are loading the DT from the CSV file, it may be easier to compute a _key_ value  (i.e.:  `Dim key As Int64 = N1 + (N2 * 1000L) + (N3 * 1000000L) + (N4 * 1000000000L) ) and add the datarow to a `Dictionary(Of Int64, List(Of DataRow))`.  That way you could scan the dictionary for keys that contain hold more than one row.

Comment: I don't think there's an existing Linq operation that would do what you want, but it would probably be fairly straightforward to modify an implementation of `Distinct` to do what you want.  Your element is an entire row, you keep a set of the distinct elements already seen, and as you iterate, you try to add to the set and yield the current element any time it's already in the set.  If you only want to return the duplicates once, you would need an additional set to keep track of the duplicate elements already returned.  A nice resource is Jon Skeet's blog, see his Edulinq posts.

Comment: What do you mean by "range of numbers"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example with a fixed length of numbers using the Tuple class.
    https://dotnetfiddle.net/mfgpZO

```
Dim numbers as Integer = 3
        Dim dt as new Data.DataTable
        dt.Columns.Add("Date", GetType(DateTime))
        For i as Integer = 1 to numbers
        dt.Columns.Add("Number" & i, GetType(integer))
        Next

    dt.rows.Add(new Object(){"12/29/2016", "1", "2", "3"})
    dt.rows.Add(new Object(){"12/30/2016", "4", "2", "3"})
    dt.rows.Add(new Object(){"12/31/2016", "1", "2", "3"})

    Dim d as new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary(Of Tuple(Of Integer, Integer, Integer), String)
    For Each row as Data.DataRow in dt.Rows


    Dim t as new Tuple(Of Integer, Integer, Integer)(row("Number1"), row("Number2"), row("Number3"))

If d.ContainsKey(t) Then
        Console.WriteLine("Duplicate Set Of Numbers " & d(t) & " " & row("Date").ToString())
    Else
        d.Add(t, row("Date").ToString())
        Console.WriteLine("Not a Duplicate")
    End If



    Next
```

Comment: using it to display the date of the duplicate

Comment: Thank you, I like this solution. Even though it isn't LINQ, it is still concise enough that it isn't a big mess.

Comment: Tuple is great way to check for equals and exists etc for a set of a limited number of simple data types because it overrrides the Equals behavior on its own, so you don't have to code that.

Answer (score 0):

This is the C# code.

*Beauty with LINQ is that once you have solution you can apply AsParallel() and run the solution in Parallel.*

**1. Map each row to an integer number.**

Following identifier function does that.

```
int identifier(DataRow dr)
{
    return row.Field<int>(0) + 
           row.Field<int>(1) * 100 +
           row.Field<int>(2) * 10000 +
           row.Field<int>(3) * 1000000;
}
```

**2. Then Group the rows by identifier and filter groups having more than one entries.**

This will provide all duplicate occurrences.

```
dt.Select(row => new { Row = row, id = identifier(row)})
  .GroupBy(r => r.id)
  .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
  .Select(g => g.First());
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of a Linq-esque "Duplicated" function.  It's a private implementation, public extension methods that do error handling are left as an exercise to the reader.  The function is designed to defer execution, traveling far enough to find the next duplicate on each iteration.

```
Private Iterator Function Duplicates(Of TSource)(ByVal source as IEnumerable(Of TSource), ByVal comparer As IEqualityComparer(Of TSource)) As IEnumerable(Of TSource)

    Dim seenElements As New HashSet(Of TSource)(comparer)
    Dim returnedElements As New HashSet(Of TSource)(comparer)

    For Each item In source
        'If adding to the set of seen elements fails, then this element is a duplicate.
        'Then, if adding to the set of returned elements succeeds, this element has not been returned before.
        If Not seenElements.Add(item) AndAlso returnedElements.Add(item) Then Yield item
    Next
End Function
```